# Managing JRE in linux

Tags: 12.04, java

Currently I'm running `Ubuntu` `2.6.8 #1 Thu Mar 24 12:02:14 UTC 2005 i686 GNU/Linux` on my system and trying to understand what kind of `java` I have.

Command `find /usr -name java` output :

```
/usr/src/php4/php4_4.3.10.orig/php-4.3.10/ext/java
/usr/src/php4_1/php4_4.3.10.orig/php-4.3.10/ext/java
/usr/src/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/j2re-1.4.2_04/usr/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/j2re-1.4.2_04/usr/java/j2re1.4.2_04/bin/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/j2re-1.4.2_04.orig/usr/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/j2re-1.4.2_04.orig/usr/java/j2re1.4.2_04/bin/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11/usr/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11/usr/java/jre1.3.1_11/bin/i386/green_threads/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11/usr/java/jre1.3.1_11/bin/i386/native_threads/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11/usr/java/jre1.3.1_11/bin/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11.orig/usr/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11.orig/usr/java/jre1.3.1_11/bin/i386/green_threads/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11.orig/usr/java/jre1.3.1_11/bin/i386/native_threads/java
/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/jre-1.3.1_11.orig/usr/java/jre1.3.1_11/bin/java
till26:/usr/src/java/cd/RPSL-1.3.3/Utilities/j2re-1.4.2_04/usr/java/j2re1.4.2_04/bin# find /usr -name java
```

I found that I have old `Java 1.3` and `1.4` installations. Can't understand how I got java 1.3. Does it comes with system installation? How to know is anything using it? How to remove old java?

I would like to install `java 1.8` on my system. What is the right place to install it to use that could be available for all users. What command I need to type for this purpose?

Where usually `java` is placed in `Debian` machines?

Comment: I'm asking quite carefully : Is it possible that you are running a very, very outdated edition of ubuntu ? - If that's the case  you urgently should install the current version 15.04 or LTS version 14.04.

Comment: Actually this is old system, but I can't update it since this is clone of many installations used in industry application and there is no resources to do that. Actually I don't see any risk since this is isolated with firewall system from internet side with closed all ports.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient way is probably to use a PPA.

I'm using the WebUpd8 PPA (https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java).

It installs the VMs under /usr/lib/jvm, and symlinks the java executable via /etc/alternatives.

```
/usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
/etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java
```

The versions you have on your system appear to be put there by a printer driver from Star?

Comment: No there is no Star printer installed in system. Actualy I don't need newest java and I don't need future updates. I just need simple java 1.6 install command like "aptitude install.."

Comment: You could follow the steps outlined in this guide: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html, and apt-get install the oracle-java6-installer package.

That being said, Java 6 has been EOL'd for a while now (no security updates), so it might be better to use a version that is still being supported (7 or 8).

Also using this method will automatically install updates (security) when you do an apt-get dist-upgrade.